# Problems creating CDF via .NET DLL

Tags: front-end, cdf-format, .netlink

I have read several posts at SE and googled a lot, but I still have difficulties to create a CDF via .NET.

My first try was the Wolfram example `MathKernelApp.exe` under `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
  "NETLink", "Examples", "Part2", "MathKernelApp", "bin", "Release"}]`

I was able to create a CDF via input:

- `UsingFrontEnd@ExportString[Table[2^i,{i,16}],"CDF"]`
- `Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory,"test.cdf"}],Table[2^i,{i, 16}]]`

My second try was to reproduce it to compile a .NET DLL, which I can link to my SQL server. I have tested two different scripts, based on MathKernelApp and SimpleLink. The first one also captures Print and Message.

First Script:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Wolfram.NETLink;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class MathLinkCLR
{
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static int Call(SqlString MLInput, out SqlString MLOutResult, out SqlString MLOutMessage, out SqlString MLOutPrint)
    {
        string strInput = (string)MLInput;
        string strMLOutResult = null;
        string strMLOutMessage = null;
        string strMLOutPrint = null;
        MLOutResult = null;
        MLOutMessage = null;
        MLOutPrint = null;
        int iRV = -1;

        if (strInput != null) {

            /* Init MathLink */
            IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
            MathKernel mathKernel;
            mathKernel = new MathKernel(ml);
            mathKernel.AutoCloseLink = true;
            mathKernel.CaptureMessages = true;
            mathKernel.CapturePrint = true;
            mathKernel.Input = null;
            mathKernel.LinkArguments = null;
            mathKernel.ResultFormat = MathKernel.ResultFormatType.InputForm;
            mathKernel.UseFrontEnd = true;

            /* Run */
            mathKernel.Compute(strInput);

            /* Results */
            strMLOutResult = (string) mathKernel.Result;
            foreach (string msg in mathKernel.Messages) strMLOutMessage += msg;
            foreach (string p in mathKernel.PrintOutput) strMLOutPrint += p;
            iRV = 0;

            /* Close MathLink */
            mathKernel.Dispose();
        }
        MLOutResult = strMLOutResult;
        MLOutMessage = strMLOutMessage;
        MLOutPrint = strMLOutPrint;
        return iRV;
    }
}
```

Second script:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Wolfram.NETLink;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class MathLinkCLR
{
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static int Call(SqlString MLInput, out SqlString MLOutResult)
    {
        string strInput = (string)MLInput;
        string strMLOutResult = null;
        MLOutResult = null;
        int iRV = -1;

        if (strInput != null) {

            /* Init MathLink */
            IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
            ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();

            /* Run */
            strMLOutResult = ml.EvaluateToInputForm(strInput, 0);
            iRV = 0;

            /* Close MathLink */
            ml.Close();
        }
        MLOutResult = strMLOutResult;
        return iRV;
    }
}
```

I can compile both scripts to a DLL, which I can link to SQL via `CREATE ASSEMBLY` (and other Windows system DLLs as ASSEMBLYs). I can also execute various Mathematica code,

**BUT**

I cannot create any CDF output (directly, or via `ExportString`). The SQL proc either hangs or returns `$Failed` as standard Mathematica return value, without any hint.

I have tried .NET Framework v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319. I **always** had to use `UsingFrontEnd` to prevent error message

*FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.Export::errelem: The Export element NotebookObject contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to CDF format.*

My questions are:

- I have used the console tool csc.exe to compile. Do I need to use the Visual Studio directly? Do I need to add other references and special compiling options?
- Do I need to load other Mathematica packages in my script, which are usually loaded by the front-end automatically?
- I have, more or less, used the MathKernelApp example. Why it is working and my dll is not?

**Any help or hint is greatly appreciated!**

---

**UPDATE**

I made some more tests and also traced the system with the Sysinternals ProcMon. The MathKernel.exe is executing a `CDF.exe` and a `CDF.jar` in one of Mathematica's system folders. Both traces look similar, but the call from within the SQL Management Studio is not working.

**Maybe someone could help me with the ProcMon trace files?**

I have also tried to execute the compiled program from within the SQL Management Studio, but it's not working, too.

**Any ideas how to proceed?**

[image: cmd]

[image: sql]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

After struggeling and trying many different things, I got thre solution; thanks to *Additive GmbH, Germany* for helping!

The SQL server needs to interact with the desktop. Therefore, you need to modify the SQL server service on your machine:

[image]